# Getting distinct values from table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Im having and issue where in my table FarmerGroups I have multiple records by BSI_Code and I am getting double results for GallonsIssued due to this inner join. Is there a way to get the unique value of GallonsIssued or a way to just get results by individual BSI_CODE

```
  With Summary as (
Select B_NAME as Branch, LOC as Location
      ,SUM(payment) as Gallons
      ,SUM(case when printed = 1 THEN Fee ELSE NULL END) as FeeCollected
      ,SUM(case when printed = 0 THEN Fee ELSE NULL END) as FeeNotCollected
      ,SUM(case when printed = 1 THEN Payment ELSE NULL END) as GallonsIssued
      ,SUM(case when printed = 0 THEN Payment ELSE NULL END) as GallonsNotIssued
 From SicbWeeklyDeliveriesFuel F Inner Join FarmerGroups G ON G.BSI_CODE = F.BSI_CODE AND G.CROP_SEASON = F.CROP_SEASON AND F.B_NAME = G.BRANCH


Where F.CROP_SEASON = @cropseason

Group By B_NAME, LOC
)

SELECT Branch
      ,Location
      ,Gallons
      ,GallonsIssued
      ,GallonsNotIssued
      ,FeeCollected
      ,FeeNotCollected
      ,((GallonsIssued/Gallons) * 100) as pct_GallonsCollected
    FROM Summary 
    Order by Location, Branch
```

For SicbWeeklyDeliveriesFuel

| BSI_CODE | Payment | LOC | CROP_SEASON | Fee | B_NAME | FNAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 66 | 125 | CZ | 5 | 12.5 | DOUGLAS | John K |
| 55 | 147 | OW | 5 | 14.7 | CALEDONIA | Tim H |
| 66 | 95 | CZ | 5 | 9.5 | DOUGLAS | John K |

For Farmer Groups

| BSI_CODE | Farmer | CROP_SEASON | BRANCH | TEST_GROUP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 66 | John K | 5 | DOUGLAS | 1A |
| 55 | Tim H | 5 | CALEDONIA | 1B |
| 66 | John K | 5 | DOUGLAS | 2A |

Answer (score 0):

Your selection for the `JOIN` of `G.BSI_CODE = F.BSI_CODE AND G.CROP_SEASON = F.CROP_SEASON AND F.B_NAME = G.BRANCH` does not uniquely define the rows.

You will need to also include `F..FNAME = G.Farmer` otherwise the first row of SicbWeeklyDeliveriesFuel (BSI_CODE = 66, CROP_SEASON = 5 and B_NAME = DOUGLAS) matches both the first and last rows of FarmerGroups.   Likewise the third row also matches the same two rows in FarmerGroups.

Comment: I added G.FARMER = F.FNAME however still getting sum of all values. I also at the top added Select Distinct FNAME at the top select statement. I just need one row of values and not all rows summed up together.

Comment: Does the TEST_GROUP value in FarmerGroup have any influence on this?   If not then you need to start from a derived table for FarmerGroup to make the entries unique:   ```WITH FG AS (SELECT DISTINCT BSI_CODE, Farmer, CROP_SEASON, BRANCH FROM FarmerGroup WHERE CROP_SEASON = 5) SELECT FNAME, B_NAME, LOC, SUM(PAYMENT) FROM SicbWeeklyDeliveriesFuel F JOIN FG G ON G.BSI_CODE = F.BSI_CODE AND G.CROP_SEASON = F.CROP_SEASON AND F.B_NAME = G.BRANCH Group By FNAME,B_NAME, LOC```

Comment: Hi Martin, There are different test groups per farmer. So yes. But i want to just get unique farmers.

Comment: I have modified the sql code to what it originally is, but dont see how I can edit it with what you stated on your last comment here to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the duplication is the field TEST_GROUP in FarmerGroups Table.
But you don't need this field in the Join.
First,a CTE to get the info you need in the join without duplicates.
then your old join to the new CTE.

Try this:

```
WITH    FarmersGroup AS
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT    
                    BSI_CODE    
                ,   CROP_SEASON 
                ,   BRANCH
            FROM    FarmerGroups
        )   
,       Summary AS
        (
            SELECT 
                    Branch              =   B_NAME
                ,   Location            =   LOC
                ,   Gallons             =   SUM(payment)
                ,   FeeCollected        =   SUM(case when printed = 1 THEN Fee      ELSE NULL END)      
                ,   FeeNotCollected     =   SUM(case when printed = 0 THEN Fee      ELSE NULL END)      
                ,   GallonsIssued       =   SUM(case when printed = 1 THEN Payment  ELSE NULL END)  
                ,   GallonsNotIssued    =   SUM(case when printed = 0 THEN Payment  ELSE NULL END)  
                
            FROM    SicbWeeklyDeliveriesFuel    F 
            JOIN    FarmerGroup                 G   ON  G.BSI_CODE      =   F.BSI_CODE
                                                    AND G.CROP_SEASON   =   F.CROP_SEASON
                                                    AND G.BRANCH        =   F.B_NAME
            WHERE   F.CROP_SEASON   =   @cropseason
            
            GROUP BY 
                    B_NAME, LOC
        )

SELECT 
        Branch
    ,   Location
    ,   Gallons
    ,   GallonsIssued
    ,   GallonsNotIssued
    ,   FeeCollected
    ,   FeeNotCollected
    ,   pct_GallonsCollected    =   ((GallonsIssued/Gallons) * 100)

FROM    Summary 

ORDER BY 
        Location
    ,   Branch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Andy's code above and it should do the job or you can just replace the table join in your current query

Change the following

```
Inner Join FarmerGroups G ON G.BSI_CODE = F.BSI_CODE AND G.CROP_SEASON = F.CROP_SEASON AND F.B_NAME = G.BRANCH
```

to

```
Inner join (select SELECT  DISTINCT    
                    BSI_CODE    
                ,   CROP_SEASON 
                ,   BRANCH
            FROM    FarmerGroups ) G on
ON G.BSI_CODE = F.BSI_CODE AND G.CROP_SEASON = F.CROP_SEASON AND F.B_NAME = G.BRANCH
```